# What role does The Word have in The Trinity?

Tags: trinity, word-of-god

So in John 1, it says that the Word was God, and I am curious as to whether the Word of God is considered part of the Father, Son, or Holy Spirit? Or is it distinct, and if so, why is it not included in part of the Trinity?

Comment: Do you mean John 1? "The Word" is one of the titles for the Son of God, Jesus Christ.

Comment: Ahh so the Word is Jesus. I see now, thank you so much for the reply

Comment: Do you want a Catholic based answer? The "Will" of God the Father is communicated thru "Word/Logos" and understand thru the "Wisdom" of the Holy Spirit. The WILL, the WORD/LOGOS and the WISDOM is the symbol of the Most Holy Trinity.So, if you want to understand the Word you need the Wisdom of the Holy Spirit. The question is who represents the Wisdom in the flesh as the Word became flesh and the Will is accepted thru Mary's FIAT. The Word got the flesh thru Mary  the Will was revealed thru Mary. Did Wisdom got also the flesh thru Mary or the Wisdom use the flesh of Mary to manifest the Will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome, and thanks for your question.

The Apostle John made clear that the Word is indeed the Son. In the first chapter of his gospel, he frames the narrative to follow as the story of the Word of God becoming a man, Jesus Christ. Here are some verses from that text:

> 1 In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God. 2 He was in the beginning with God. 3 All things came into being through Him, and apart from Him nothing came into being that has come into being. 4 In Him was life, and the life was the Light of men. ... 9 There was the true Light which, coming into the world, enlightens every man. ... 14 And the Word became flesh, and dwelt among us, and we saw His glory, glory as of the only begotten from the Father, full of grace and truth. ... 17 For the Law was given through Moses; grace and truth were realized through Jesus Christ.

So, when used in a trinitarian sense, the "Word" or "Logos" of God is synonymous with "the Son", each being interpreted to mean the person Jesus Christ.

Comment: How did I miss this answer last year?  Welcome to the 5000 club, Andrew.  You do good work.

Answer (score 4):

John's gospel uses the Greek word *Logos* which is translated as *Word.* Logos is the Greek term translated as “word,” “speech,” “principle,” or “thought.” In Greek philosophy, it also referred to a universal, divine reason or the mind of God.

To make it absolutely clear who John is talking about, after saying (in verse 3) that through him all things were made, verse 14 goes on to explain:

> The Word became flesh and made his dwelling among us.

Jesus, the Son, is the Word, or Logos, who was with God in the beginning and who condescended to lower himself and come to earth to be born of a woman.  Jesus is God incarnate and part of the One Being of God.